# Hide Multiple Choice field with jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, 2016, list-form

I have a field in an SP 2016 form that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to hide the row that the multi choice field is in. I've tried multiple things.

#1 doesn't work at all. #2 hides the check boxes but does not hide the label.

Any ideas?

```
1. $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("OTA Inputter Assigned To")').parent().hide();  // not working
2. $("#OTA_x0020_Approval_x0020_Assigne_ceec15dd-2bc9-4bc1-b073-8dec25315df2_MultiChoiceTable input:checkbox").closest('tr').hide(); // kind of works but doesn't hide the label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
$('nobr:contains("OTA Inputter Assigned To")').closest('tr').hide();
```

OR

```
$("span.ms-standardheader:contains('OTA Inputter Assigned To')").closest("tr").hide();
```

I just tried this on my SharePoint site & it is working for me.